How to get PPPD to work with systemd-networkd?
This appears similar to another question, but nothing was ever followed up on it.
I'm currently having trouble with pppd as a systemd service. I'm waiting for the network adapter to come online before attempting to setup the pppoe link. The service:
[Unit]
Description=PPPoE connection
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pppd call dsl-provider
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth1.device

Where eth1 is the device upon which the pppoe link will be made.
Inspection of the service's logs with journalctl -u pppoe.service shows:
debian systemd[1]: Starting pppoe.service - PPPoE connection...
debian pppd[3833]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
debian pppd[3833]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
debian pppd[3834]: pppd 2.4.9 started by root, uid 0
debian pppd[3834]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
debian pppd[3834]: Unable to complete PPPoE Discovery
...
debian pppd[3834]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
debian pppd[3834]: Unable to complete PPPoE Discovery
debian pppd[3834]: Exit.
debian systemd[1]: pppoe.service: Deactivated successfully.
debian systemd[1]: Finished pppoe.service - PPPoE connection.

This is the same whether the service is run automatically at boot or with systemctl start pppoe. When pppd is run manually with pppd call dsl-provider it works as expected.
What could be causing this issue? Thanks

hm, which network managing service are you using? Haven't set up pppd ever with systemd, because systemd came with a network manager that had a PPPoE plugin to begin with, making that unnecessary.

I'm using systemd-networkd to set up my network interfaces, etc.

ah, I guess that's the difference – I know that NetworkManager does support PPPoE, I think netctl does, too, but I don't think systemd-networkd does. Hm, I don't know how wise it would be to mix and match different network managers … probably not much. So, sorry, can't be very helpful :(

as which user do you run pppd when you run it manually?

I run it with sudo, so UID 0/root. No worries, thanks anyway. Making pppd a systemd service is mainly to automatically establish a ppp connection when eth1 is brought up (as there's no if-up in networkd)

and it makes sense you would do that; that's sensible. Maybe add the path to your ppp config and its content (cleaned from confidential data), in case someone spots anything about that

Changed Type to forking and it seems to work ok. I figured because pppd appears to become a background service that it might be better to use that type instead.
